# Smallest Multiple to "Palindromize"

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence, palindrome

## Goal:

Given any non-zero natural number `a`, find the smallest non-zero natural
number `b` such that `a•b` is palindromic, e.g. it reads the same forwards and backwards. Input `a` through any reasonable means (STDIN, function argument, etc.), And output `b` through any reasonable means (STDOUT, function return value.)

## Notes:

- Input will not always have a solution (multiples of 10), so you must create an error, or display -1/0
- Input validation is not necessary, assume `a` is a natural number.
- Standard loopholes apply (Hardcoding, using a language created after this challenge)

## Examples:

```
a=34, b=8 (272)
a=628, b=78 (48984)
a=15, b=35 (525)
a=33, b=1 (33)
a=20, (Error, -1, or 0)
```

Comment: How do we know if the input has a solution or not? Or is figuring that out part of the challenge?

Comment: As far as I can tell, only multiples of 10 do not have solutions.

Comment: Do we have to "detect" that there is no solution or can we e.g. go into an infinite loop which will eventually throw an error?

Comment: Some are harder to find (powers of 3), I needed some time for 243 and 729, but it seems to work for every n given enough time

Comment: [Related Math.SE post.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/339081/50421) Yes, every number that isn't a multiple of 10 has a palindromic multiple.

Comment: @JulianLachniet hey, you seems to like a leaderboard on your question, you can just copy the one in `Pyramid of broken strings`, change the `QUESTION_ID` and `OVERRIDE_USER` to this question id (106336) and to your id (well that question is yours too, so you don't need to change this one)

Comment: Can someone explain how to contact a moderator about reopening this question?

Comment: @JulianLachniet Having `a*b=c` where `a` is given and `c` is a palindrome, your question asks to output 'b', the linked question asks to output 'c'. There is really very little difference...

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
&eQf_I`*Q
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26eQf_I%60%2aQ&input=628&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
&eQf_I`*QT    Implicitly append T, and take input in Q. 
 eQ           Calculate input mod 10.
&             Logical and, only evaluate the following if result ≠ 0.
   f          Starting from 1, find the first integer T for which... 
      `       ...the string representation of... 
       *QT    ...input multiplied by T... 
    _I        ...is equal to its reverse.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 51 bytes

```
->a{(1..a%10/0.0).find{|b|(c="#{a*b}")==c.reverse}}
```

#### Explanation

```
        a%10/0.0 # -> NaN for multiples of 10, Infinity otherwise
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
T%            # input mod 10
  0›          # is greater than 0
    µ         # repeat the following until counter reaches that number (0 or 1)
     ¹N*      # input * iteration
        ÂQ    # is equal to its reverse
          ½   # if true, increase counter
              # implicitly output last iteration (or 0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@x@iavCoYdehrYd2@mkdbgo8tPf/fzMjCwA)

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>108</s> 101 bytes

*Thanks to @nmjcman101 for 7 bytes!*

```c
m,o;f(n){for(o=0;n;)o=o*10+n%10,n/=10;return o;}g(n){m=-1;if(n%10)for(m=1;n*m!=f(n*m);m++);return m;}
```

Is C the only language here with no built-in reversing/checking palindrome function?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#NcsxCsMwDIXhq7SBgGS71KLdhA5TSBw8SComnULOnjhD1/f@79DkXMBwK97AJbMxunigHG2knOwplLnN66/ZzXlfrlblQVw76wVeUIXYgt6lb0GRNUb8I@X90E81wO3bqq0FhnEa0gKvN2L/Tg)

Comment: Could you change the `for` in `g` to `for(m=1;n*m!=f(n*m));`, initialize `m=-1;` earlier in `g` and then just return `m`.  `g(n){m=-1;if(n%10)for(m=1;n*m!=f(n*m);m++);return m;}` (I think you could throw `++m` in the condition, but check that)

Comment: @nmjcman101 thanks! I saw your comment before editing, tried `++m` in various places, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 113 bytes

```
i->{int j=1;for(String a;!new StringBuilder(a=String.valueOf(i*j)).reverse().toString().equals(a);)j++;return j;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>78</s> <s>66</s> 60 bytes

```
def f(a):
 b=a%10!=0
 while `a*b`!=`a*b`[::-1]:b+=1
 print b
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@5@SmqaQppGoacWlkGSbqGpooGhrwKVQnpGZk6qQkKiVlKBoC6airax0DWOtkrRtDbkUCooy80oUkv6naRibaHKlaZgZWYAoQ1MQaWwMIo0MNP9zcQEA)

Comment: That's a nice answer, you can still golf it down.

Comment: Improved it a bit by simplifying the b check.

Comment: You can drop that `;` and use a single space instead of 4 spaces. Also, use `print b` by changing it to Python 2. After all this it'll be `66 bytes`.

Comment: I've written too much c code in my life :) I think I could also simplifiy the str() casts when using python 2.

Comment: Yea, I forgot that you can use `a` instead of `str(a)` in python 2, that's saves a lot too. Also, what encoding you are using, UTF-8 is fine here, so `\n` is 1 byte.

Comment: Good point, changed my editor byte count to use \n instead of \r\n.

Answer (score 1):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 29 bytes

```
:{c=a*q~!c$=_f!c$||_Xq\q=q+1
```

Explanation:

```
:      Get cmd line param as number 'a'
{      DO
c=a*q  multiply 'a' by 'q' and assign to 'c', which is 1 at the start of a QBIC program
~      IF
!c$    'c' cast to string
=      equals
_f!c$| 'c' cast to string, the reversed
|      THEN
_Xq    Quit, printing 'q'
\q=q+1 ELSE increment q and rerun
       DO Loop is auto-closed by QBIC, as is the IF
```

Eventually, 'q' will overflow and throw an error on an unsolvable 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 43 bytes

```
If[10∣#,0,#//.x_/;!PalindromeQ@x:>x+#]/#&
```

#### Explanation

```
If[10∣#,0,...]/#&
```

If the input is a multiple of 10, return 0 (divided by the input).

```
#//....
```

Otherwise, repeatedly apply the following substitution to the input.

```
x_/;!PalindromeQ@x
```

Match a value which is not a palindrome.

```
...:>x+#
```

And replace that value with itself plus the input. This repeated substitution therefore searches through consecutive multiples of the input until it finds a palindrome.

```
.../#
```

Finally, to figure out `b` we simply divide the result by the input again.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```
f a|a`mod`10==0=0|1>0=[b|b<-[1..],show(a*b)==reverse(show$a*b)]!!0
```

Returns 0 if `a` is a multiple of 10. Will check from 1 to infinity for `b` if the textual reverse of `a*b` is the same as `a*b`.

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 68 bytes

```py
x,y=input(),1
if not x%10:x+''
while `x*y`!=`y*x`[::-1]:y+=1
print y
```

Outputs an error if input is a multiple of 10.